# Gulp vinyl-ftp newer and different size files does not upload

Tags: javascript, node.js, ftp, gulp, ftp-client

[vinyl-ftp](https://github.com/morris/vinyl-ftp#usage) has this feature to upload new and different size files conn.differentSize( remoteFolder[, options] )

I am trying to test that only newer files would upload and so far nothing is happening, files just are not uploading. Here my configuration.

```
gulp.task( 'deploy', function() {

var conn = ftp.create( {
    host:     hostremote,
    user:     userremote,
    password: passremote,
    parallel: 10,
    log:true
} );

var globs = [
    '*',
    'build/**',
    'dist/**',
    'fonts/**',
    'html/**',
    'IE6/**',
    'images/**',
    'include/**',
    'js/**',
    'language/**',
    'lib/**',
    '!node_modules',
    '!original',
    '!node_modules/**',
    '!original/**'


];

// using base = '.' will transfer everything to /public_html correctly 
// turn off buffering in gulp.src for best performance 

return gulp.src( globs, { base: '.', buffer: false } )
    .pipe( conn.newerOrDifferentSize( '/test2' ) )
      .pipe( conn.dest('/test') );} );
```

Any thoughts ?

Comment: Why your remote folders are different in `conn.newerOrDifferentSize` and `conn.dest` calls?

Comment: Just to test things out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Heikki points out, the remote paths must be the same; otherwise `newerOrDifferentSize` will compare `images/foo.png` with `test2/images/foo.png`, and then definitely upload to `test/images/foo.png`.

If that does not fix it, would you mind opening an issue at https://github.com/morris/vinyl-ftp with your full log, and possibly your FTP server software? This might be a bug then.